# Google Analytics retrieve custom variables statistics

Tags: variables, google-analytics

**Edit** *refurbished the question that was not clear*

New to GA, I'm looking at the way to retrieve automatically custom variables data statistics

The query would have

- a *start* and an *end* dates (possibly equal)
- a *variable* name

For instance, a *Page-level* variable `Brand` takes only three possible values, that are set by the web server, and seen by the client.
The values are *Apple*, *Google* and *Microsoft*.

The query to Google-Analytics could be something like (pseudo-code), provided that I use an authentication token previously acquired

```
  ...getstatistics?myToken=123&variable=Brand&datefrom=20110121&dateto=20110121
```

And the result could be some xml like data

```
  <variable>Brand</variable><value>Apple</value><count>3214</count> 
  <variable>Brand</variable><value>Google</value><count>4321</count> 
  <variable>Brand</variable><value>Microsoft</value><count>1345</count>
```

Meaning for instance that the page-level custom variable *Brand* was set to the value *Apple* by the web server (and thus seen by the client / sent to GA) 3214 times.

What is the correct way/protocol to query values/statistics from GA, in order to get statistics related to custom variables?

Comment: I'd love to try to answer this, but I'm still not totally clear what you're trying to do. Are the numbers next to Brand Values associated with the Custom Variables? How is this data presented in GA? Do you have a unique identifier for each user in your data?

Comment: The question has been edited!

Comment: thanks! i'll take a crack at it and see if I can do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, this is my understanding of what you're doing:

You're setting page-level custom variables (important technical note: these need to be called before the _trackPageview or some other call, else they won't be tracked.)

Your code might looks something like this:

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 2, 'Brand', 3]);
```

Now, when querying the Google Analytics API, its important to note that the slot # is very important, since the slot you're accessing is explicitly named in the query.

So, to do this, you'd need to set your dimensions to `ga:customVarName2` and `ga:customVarValue2`, and decide what metric you're interesting it getting. You mention Page views, so you'd use `ga:pageviews`. (You're by no means limited to pageviews. You can use any Metric besides a couple of the AdWords specific ones.)

This query would return you all of the custom variable from this slot, and the number of pageviews associated with them.

You also mentioned you'd want to be able to filter by value.

You'd do that by setting the filter value to something like `ga:customVarValue2==Apple`.

You can see what a query like that [would look like here in the query explorer](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataExplorer.html?dimensions=ga%253AcustomVarName2%252Cga%253AcustomVarValue2&metrics=ga%253Apageviews&filters=ga%253AcustomVarValue1%253D%253DApple&start-date=2011-01-16&end-date=2011-01-30&max-results=50).

Here's a sample screenshot:
[image]

Finally, all Google Analytics API queries by default require you to set a date range, so you could query that on your own.

All you need to do is decide [which library](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataLibraries.html) you want to use as interface, and you're set to go.

Comment: Thanks, it seems we can use GA for our needs - a developer will have a look at the library, but this is a good start anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Google has a handy resource, called the [Google Analytics Data Explorer](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataExplorer.html) that can help answer a lot of your questions by letting you experiment through an interface, as long as you login with your Google Analytics credentials.

As you add parameters using their tools, the system will automatically build your URL/Query.

If that's not enough, Google also has some [Interactive Examples using JavaScript](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataInteractiveSamples.html).  Like the Data Explorer, you can also login with your Google Analytics credentials and run the examples to see what data would be returned.

These tools are awesome because they help take the guesswork out of figuring out how to target the exact data you're searching for.

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind to show some code (not Javascript) running at the company that would query the data as explained in my example above?

Comment: @ring0 - Considering it's custom variables, I'm not sure that will help you unless you expose your website and code to us here.  I'm hoping that -- with what I've provided -- you can put those problem solving skills of yours to use and figure the rest out.  :)  Or you can further clarify your question for specifics.  Are you confused about how to build the query string or how to write code that pulls the data available at that query?

Comment: @jmort253 The reason there is a 100 attached to the question is I was expecting someone with a past experience with retrieving custom-variables from GA to make an answer based on the Brand problem above, providing relevant implementation advices, avoiding me to make research and tests. I thought the 'Brand' problem was more understandable (than in my original question). We want to know if we go for GA or with something else. So basically I want to be sure the variables can be retrieved given some parameters, and some code would prove it more efficiently.

Comment: @ring0 - I don't understand what's so difficult.  It seems this question could be answered by you setting some variables and then pulling them yourself from the resulting URL querystring.  No coding required whatsoever.  Isn't REST great?! REST allows GETs to retrieve the data.  So you should be able to answer this in about 5 minutes yourself with the tools I've given you and nothing more than a Web browser.  You also didn't answer the question I asked about what you are confused about.  The more information you provide, the better answers you will get, regardless of what the bounty is.

Comment: @jmort253 Took some time today and looked at the data you and *yc* provided, and was amazed as how **well** that system is made, and how powerful it is. We can definitely use GA, and it is even better than what we thought initially. I thought I could split the bounty by clicking on it, but it seems it is not possible.

Comment: @ring0 - Awesome!  Glad to hear that worked out for you.  And as far as the bounty goes, a picture speaks a thousand words.  @yc earned it.